# selecting certain columns from parent model with Eloquent laravel

Tags: php, model, laravel-5, relationship

I make mode for the name of **Content**

```
class Content extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * Get Images
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class, 'content_id')->orderBy('sort');
    }
}
```

Still i am using the following code in **controller**

```
$data = \App\Models\Content::has('images')
                                   ->leftJoin('content_relations AS r', 'contents.id', '=', 'r.content_id')
                                   ->leftJoin('products AS p', 'contents.id', '=', 'p.content_id')
                                   ->whereIn('r.category_id', [1, 2, 3])
                                   ->groupBy('contents.id')->take(4)->get();
```

it's giving me record for images when i call

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    var_dump($row->images);
}
```

If i changed the code in **controller** for get the certain columns from **Content Model**, just added select function

```
$data = \App\Models\Content::has('images')->select('title', 'cover', 'slug')
                                           ->leftJoin('content_relations AS r', 'contents.id', '=', 'r.content_id')
                                           ->leftJoin('products AS p', 'contents.id', '=', 'p.content_id')
                                           ->whereIn('r.category_id', [1, 2, 3])
                                           ->groupBy('contents.id')->take(4)->get();
```

Then it's not return data in

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
    var_dump($row->images);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling an images relations on $data which doesn't have id

your image function in content class will need content_id.
So you have to select the id when you are fetching the data,

Try this

```
$data = \App\Models\Content::has('images')->select('content.id','title', 'cover', 'slug')
                                       ->leftJoin('content_relations AS r', 'contents.id', '=', 'r.content_id')
                                       ->leftJoin('products AS p', 'contents.id', '=', 'p.content_id')
                                       ->whereIn('r.category_id', [1, 2, 3])
                                       ->groupBy('contents.id')->take(4)->get();
```

Comment: Glad to help imran. please accept this answer for helping other who comes acroos this kind of issue

Answer (score 1):

You will have to include the `id` for your content rows because I suppose this is how the images are linked to your content model. If you do not include this, there is no way to link the content model to these images.

Also, consider using [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), this will load all images beforehand and uses less queries.

```
$data = \App\Models\Content::has('images')
    ->with('images')
    ->select('id', 'title', 'cover', 'slug')
    ->leftJoin('content_relations AS r', 'contents.id', '=', 'r.content_id')
    ->leftJoin('products AS p', 'contents.id', '=', 'p.content_id')
    ->whereIn('r.category_id', [1, 2, 3])
    ->groupBy('contents.id')->take(4)->get();
```

You should also create a relation for the products, this will make your code much cleaner and allows for eager loading here as well.